# PHP issue with Chinese characters

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, phalcon, cjk

I have tried all the possible solutions listed on SOF, but not a single solution works for me *(Maybe am doing something not appropriate)*.
Recently I have upgraded my infra, upgraded from PHP 5 to PHP 7 and then problem start, old infra still displaying all the Chinese character very well not an issue, but on PHP 7 I have an issue. It's display question marks only and few Chinese characters, i.e. **`广?????运货运代?????????????????司`**

**MariaDB**

```
'character_set_client','utf8'
'character_set_connection','utf8'
'character_set_database','utf8'
'character_set_filesystem','binary'
'character_set_results','utf8'
'character_set_server','utf8'
'character_set_system','utf8'
'character_sets_dir','c:\\mariadb\\share\\charsets\\'
```

**MariaDB Table Data**

```
'4181','é“ç”²å…µæˆ·å¤–','TB0001',NULL,'2016-06-04 18:21:35',NULL,NULL
'4188','é“ç”²å…µæˆ·å¤–','TB0001',NULL,'2016-06-04 18:24:20',NULL,NULL
'4221','é“ç”²å…µæˆ·å¤–(TB0001)','TB0001',NULL,'2016-06-05 05:09:49','2016-08-24 06:54:57',NULL
'204424','å¹¿å·žå‡Œè¿è´§è¿ä»£ç†æœåŠ¡æœ‰é™å…¬å¸',NULL,NULL,'2019-07-09 00:13:43','2020-02-19 10:08:21',NULL
```

**Maria DB Table Definition**

```
CREATE TABLE `companies` (
  `entity_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `reg_no` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `website_url` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  KEY `fk_companies_1_idx` (`entity_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `ft_1` (`reg_no`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_8244AA3A81257D5D` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `entities` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**PHP 7 Input**

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connect failed: %s\n". $conn -> error);

$query = "SELECT * FROM companies where entity_id = 4188";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$name = $row["name"];
echo "\n";
echo $name;
echo "\n";
echo utf8_decode($name);
echo "\n";
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $name);
echo "\n";
echo mb_convert_encoding($name, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
echo "\n";
echo  utf8_decode($name);
```

**PHP 7 Output**

```
é“ç”²å…µæˆ·å¤–
??????????????

??????????????
??????????????
```

*This is my old infra*

**PHP 5 Input**

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connect failed: %s\n". $conn -> error);

$query = "SELECT * FROM companies where entity_id = 4188";//204424";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$name = $row["name"];
echo $name;
```

**PHP 5 Output**

```
铁甲兵户外
```

On both Interfaces I'm using the same database, but somehow on old infra the output is okay without any conversion of utf or latin.

Comment: In mariadb - utf8 (defaults to  3 byte) -> utf8mb4 (4 byte per char utf8). Table defination is important too - `show create table companies`.

Answer (score 0):

`ç”²å…µæˆ·å¤–` is Mojibake for `甲兵户外`

Mojibake occurs when something is incorrectly indicating `latin1` (or some wrong character set).

For Chinese, you need `utf8mb4`, not imply `utf8`.

Do not use any encoders/decoders, then only mess things up worst.

For debugging, use hex.  In MySQL, use `SELECT col, hex(col) ...`

More on "best practice", Mojibake, etc:  [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)